# Como deixar o teclado virtual do Android visível/invisível enquanto o TEdit está em foco

Tags: android, delphi, teclado, firemonkey

Eu uso `Delphi XE7`, queria saber como tratar essa questão, seto o foco no `TEdit`, ele abre o teclado virtual do `Android`, aperto o voltar ele fecha o teclado e o foco permanece no `TEdit`, mas quando eu aperto novamente no TEdit enquanto o mesmo está em foco ele não abre mais o teclado virtual.

Alguém tem alguma ideia de como resolver?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Não tenho como testar agora, mas tente o seguinte código no `OnEnter` do Edit:

```
procedure TForm1.Edit1Enter(Sender: TObject);
var
  VKbSvc: IFMXVirtualKeyboardService;
begin    
  if TPlatformServices.Current.SupportsPlatformService(IFMXVirtualKeyboardService, VKbSvc) then
  begin
      VKbSvc.ShowVirtualKeyboard(Edit1);
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Não adiantou, pois o TEdit já está com o foco, tem como verificar se o próprio TEdit está com o foco setado, assim eu conseguiria verificar e então abrir o teclado é uma ideia.

Comment: Você disse na pergunta "quando eu seto o foco novamente". Se o TEdit já tem o foco, tenta colocar o código no `OnClick` ou `OnTap` do TEdit.

Comment: "quando eu seto o foco novamente no TEdit enquanto o mesmo ta em foco", também não adianta, já tentei.

Comment: editei a pergunta, não fui claro. Desculpa.

Comment: Tente o seguinte código no `OnClick` `edit1.resetfocus;` `edit1.setfocus;` e mantenha o código do `OnEnter`

Comment: consegui resolver, usando a mesma ideia que você me passou, ao invés de colocar no OnClick, usei o evento OnMouseEnter para ele abrir o teclado e o OnExit para fechar o teclado, no ViewSource no projeto setei o VKAutoShowMode := TVKAutoShowMode.Never, assim consigo controlar o teclado quando deve ser fechado e aberto. Obrigado pela ajuda

Answer (score 3):

Tente utilizar a variável global `VKAutoShowMode := TVKAutoShowMode.vkasAlways`, para que o teclado sempre apareça. Não esqueça também de incluir a unit `FMX.Types` no projeto, pois é onde esta variável global reside.

Comment: a sua sugestão deu uma ideia de eu controlar o teclado virtual, quando deve ser fechado ou aberto, no ViewSource do projeto, setei o VLAutoShowMode :=TVKAutoShowMode.Never. Obrigado pela ajuda.

Answer (score 1):

Não tenho como testar agora, mas tente o seguinte código no OnEnter do Edit:

```
procedure TForm1.Edit1Enter(Sender: TObject); var   VKbSvc: IFMXVirtualKeyboardService; begin       if TPlatformServices.Current.SupportsPlatformService(IFMXVirtualKeyboardService, VKbSvc) then   begin
      VKbSvc.ShowVirtualKeyboard(Edit1);   end; end;
```

Complementando a solução do colega, para usar isso é necessário colocar `FMX.VirtualKeyboard` e `FMX.Platform` nas importações(uses).